ADF dataflow Blob storage to kusto Ingestion keeps running
My ADF dataflow which copies simple json file from blob storage to kusto table keeps running. Within the pipeline run,transformation status shows success and number of rows written is shown. But the job is not completing and kusto has no data as well. It is reproducible in copy activity as well. If I use storage to storage connector, the data is copied in 3 minutes. Hence, I believe data size is not the issue



can you check the data once by reconnecting kusto?


transformation status shows success and number of rows written is shown. But the job is not completing and Kusto has no data as well

Please check that the data transformation and mapping between the source (blob storage) and the destination (Kusto table) are correctly configured. Sometimes, incorrect mappings or transformations can cause issues during the data transfer process. Verify that the datatypes of the Kusto table matches the structure of the JSON file schema. Any discrepancies in the schema and data types can cause loss of data.

Please check the sink data preview before running the dataflow if there is any error occurring.

I'm able to view the data in sink preview. So no issue with data type. For pipeline in the screenshot, are you able to ingest into kusto without delay ? If yes, what auth are you using in the linked service ? I'm using managed identity

I have also used managed identity authentication an i am able to ingest data in Kusto
